# No output PDFfile produced - mathmode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, output

There is no pdf file produced even though no warning is shown. If I replace the formula with some text, the pdf output is produced.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\let\Tiny=\tiny>
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}

\frac{e^x}{2*y}

\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

edit:

ok. but that doesn't solve the problem. A more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  $e^x$
\end{frame}  
 \end{document}
```

No Output fle produced, no warning. I am using TeXnicCenter and Miktex. Maybe it is not compatible with beamer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would expect an error message due to the empty lines before and after `\frac`... What should `\tiny>` do and `\Tiny`???.

Comment: The modified example should give errors (`Missing \begin{document}`): are you really trying to run this?

Comment: Ops, you're right. I forgot \begin{document} . But the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Lisa There will be a file in your folder, the name of your main tex file, ending log (you might ne switch on file endings in the windows explorer). Please show us that file.

Comment: there is no .log file. LaTex says there are no warnings or mistakes

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the usage of `\Tiny` (unless it's a beamer - internal command), but the empty lines before and after `\frac` in the `align*` environment are wrong.

There are some other points which should be improved

- As it stands, the `align*` environment is not necessary, a `\[...\]` would do as well
- '*' looks weird as multiplication symbol use `\cdot` or something similar for this.

---

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\let\Tiny=\tiny
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\frac{e^x}{2\cdot y}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]